# Create a Rule that assigns a specific role to a user after they have completed a form

Tags: 7, users, rules, webforms

Ok, I have a customer that is wanting to have an applicant complete a specific webform and then have their user account be assigned to a specific role automatically.

My thought was to go the following route using rules:

1. Applicant creates their user account
2. They are then automatically taken to the specific webform
3. Once the webform is completed, then they are automatically assigned a specific role *(this is the part where I'm lost as to the best option or if it's even possible)*

Is this something that would even be possible using rules? Or are there other options that may work? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

I hope I've explained the situation enough :) Let me know if you need any further info.

Thank You!!

Nicole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can! This is a way of doing it with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

This also requires the [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) Module.

Download that, enable it, and be sure that the Rules UI module within it is enabled as well.

### Step 1 - Create Rule

Start by creating a new Rule under Admin>Config>Workflow>Rules.

Name it whatever you'd like, but have it react on "After a webform has been submitted"

[image: Create new Rule]

---

### Step 2 - Find Webform's NID

In another tab, view your Webforms in Content>Webforms. Hover your mouse over the Edit link next to the Webform you were talking about to find its Node ID (NID). You will need this in a second.

[image: View Webforms]

[image: Webform NID]

---

### Step 3 - Only Apply Rule to that Particular Webform

Return to the Rule you created a bit ago and click the "Add condition" link under "Conditions".

[image: Conditions]

Select "Data Comparison" as your condition.

Here, you are going to select "node:nid". This is because you only want this rule to fire up when the Webform you mentioned earlier is submitted.

Below that, enter in the Node ID for the Webform

[image: nid]

---

### Step 4 - Add Action for Adding Role

Return to your Rule and click on the "Add Action" link in the "Actions" settings.

[image: Add Action]

For your Action, you are going to select "Add user role"

[image: User Role]

Under the Data selector, you are going to choose "user"

[image]

Below that, select the Role(s) that you want the submitter to gain.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much for this! a couple of things... when i go to create a new rule, i'm not seeing anything re: completion of webform and i don't see an option for "add a user role "add user role"... i'm not too terribly familiar with rules, so is there something i need to do to get more items available? Here is what I see in the drop down: https://app.box.com/s/u6cucod1cifrgnner7pabksam16xwjse - any additional assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Nicole, sorry about that! I edited my post. You need the Webform Rules Module as well for those options to be available. Hope that helps!